# Delete folders specific folder in adf

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have the follwing set of activities ( see below image) which deletes the folders which are older than 5 days. My path looks like this bronze/D365/Snapshot/salestable/"todaydate"/*.parquet. Below pipeline deletes folders from `salestable` folder.

[image]

In the get metadataactivity I have following settings:
[image]

where the folder_path is only pointing( hardcoded) SalesTable.

My goal is to make this dynamic and pass all the table names as I dont have only salestable there.

I tired to but the entire pipeline under ForEach loop and before for each loop another Getmetada activty which gives all the table names. Like this:

[image]

my problem is that I dont know how to pass the value from the Getmetadata_Of_ALL inside ForEach activity for get metadata activity dataset. So dataset filepath will become dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use get metadata on `bronze/D365/Snapshot/` path as use field list as `child items` to get list of folders inside this path (since you have multiple folders along with salesTable).
- The following is the demo of the same. I have folder structure as `data/a/b` inside which I have 3 folders (like salesTable and inside which I have todays date folder). I have used get Metadata on these and got the result as shown below:

[image]

- Now iterate through each of these folders. Inside for each, use another get metadata activity with dataset JSON as below:

```
{
    "name": "csv2",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "adls1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "folder_name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "a/b/@{dataset().folder_name}",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "fileSystem": "data"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    }
}
```

- Pass the value for folder_name parameter from the get metadata activity as `@item().name`.

[image]

- This would give the contents of each of the folders returned in the first get metadata activity which can be further used.

[image]